# Teeth exam or tooth exam

Tags: grammatical-number

Which of the following is correct?

I got a teeth exam done.
I got a tooth exam done.

Comment: I think this question belongs on English Language Learners rather than here on ELU. The answer, though, is definitely the singular version - tooth exam. I am not sure why, or if it is related to a larger grammatical rule.

Comment: The idiomatic phrase would be "dental exam."

Comment: In English, nouns used like adjectives are almost always singular: *an apple pie*, not *an apples pie*; *a horse race*, not *a horses races*; *a shoe store*, not *a shoes store*, etc.

Comment: [These Google 2-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tooth+exam%2Cteeth+exam%2Coral+examination%2Cdental+examination&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) present, IMO, pretty convincing back-up for the idiomaticity only of other alternatives (mentioned by @alphabet).  One _can_ restrict the search to just your two offered alternatives, when admittedly it can be seen that neither flatlines ... but both are best avoided. / Attributive nouns normally default to the singular form (qv on ELU). / 'Exam' is rare for a medical examination.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It should be noted that many of the uses of "oral exam" are referring to education, not medicine.

Comment: @alphabet. Yes – I should have mentioned (or omitted). Highly relevant.

Answer (score 2):

The grammatical rule is that, in English, **adjectives are not inflected for number.**

> I have twelve **red** apples.

This can be applied to other situations such as *attributive nouns,* where a noun like *tooth* is used as an adjective describing the examination.

> I got a tooth exam done.
> [Notwithstanding the unusual nature of the term "tooth exam"]

> I have twelve **door** frames.
> I have a **book** list.

Comment: I'm not sure the comparison with adjectives is all that helpful. Attributive usages relate directly to intercategorial polysemes (the nouns), for which plural forms are common. And of course the 'rule' is far from absolute, with barely explicable exceptions: _donkey sanctuary_, but _dogs' home_, or increasingly _dogs home_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You're welcome to write a more complete answer. *Dogs' home* is definitely different from a *dog home* though, and it's the possessive (whether it's lost its apostrophe or not) which makes it different.

Comment: It's already answered (not this actual example) on ELU.